# ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea returns Value ""

Tags: excel, vba

In my function below, I get an error SOMETIMES. It's not always when I change a sheet and use the same sub routine I get a runtime error.

`ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea` returns EMPTY

In fact I click the activesheet but it's not refreshing.

```vb
Sub createJpg(nameFile As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    'Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate
    Set Plage = Range(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea) ' Here
    Plage.CopyPicture
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
Set Plage = Nothing
End Sub
```

but,
it works sometime so I could not understand why it's not working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You haven't set a print area, so it's empty.

Comment: I've not used the `PrintArea` property much before at all, but when setting the property an empty string `""` sets it to the entire sheet, perhaps when it's returning that value it's set to the entire sheet? [MS Documentation for PrintArea Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea)

Comment: Yes I realised that setting PrintArea and adusting Pageview or Normal view is totally different. It was OK for PrintPreview but I found that I need to Right click the cells and I need to set printing Area.